# Equivalent of a "mdfind" query in Ack: AND operator + -interpret switch

Tags: regex, linux, macos, ack

I am trying to modify Brett Terpstra's handy [QuickQuestion script](https://github.com/ttscoff/QuickQuestion/blob/master/qq) for my Linux machine. What would be Ack's equivalent to the following `mdfind` commands:

```
mdfind -onlyin "$NOTESDIR" "filename:.$NOTESEXT AND filename:\"$NOTESPRE\" AND ${INPUT%\?}"
...
echo "`mdfind -onlyin \"$NOTESDIR\" -interpret \"filename:.$NOTESEXT AND filename:$NOTESPRE AND ${INPUT%\?}\"`"
```

I can't seem to get the AND part right. I understand that one has to use parentheses since Ack is Perl. But for example `(?="$NOTESPRE")(?="$INPUT")` gave errors.

Furthermore, I am not sure what to do with the `-interpret` switch on the second line.

Puzzled with such a simple query... Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double lookaheads need a range of things to consider, so you need to add wildcards to their patterns, for example:

```
>>echo "foo bar \$NOTESPRE \$INPUT baz" | ack "^(?=.*$NOTESPRE)(?=.*$INPUT).*$"
```

returns:

```
foo bar $NOTESPRE $INPUT baz
```

If you need to search a particular directory for files containing this line, just specify the directory on the command line:

```
ack "^(?=.*$NOTESPRE)(?=.*$INPUT).*$" path\to\directoryToSearch
```

`-interpret` has no direct parallel in regex.